# Setting a Custom SBL in Junos UTM

Tags: spam, junos, utm

I am looking for how to set a custom SBL, zen.spamhaus.org instead of the default msgsecurity.juniper.net, in Junos UTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Juniper's [own online documentation](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos-security/junos-security10.1/junos-security-cli-reference/utm-security-sbl-default-server-statement.html):

> *Configure the default SBL server lookup as enabled or disabled. If you are using server-based spam filtering, you should enter sbl-default-server to enable the default SBL server. **(The SBL server is predefined on the device. It ships with the name and address of the SBL server.)***

Doesn't sound like you can do that